# How to pull parallel array data from user input

Tags: c#, arrays, parallel-processing

I'm trying to pull and use data from an array that's put together based on input from the user. For example, I have a number of car parts that can be purchased, each with it's own part cost and labor costs included in its array column.

```
string[] PartName = new string[] { "WIPERBLADES", "TIRES", "BATTERY", "OIL", "OILFILTER" };
decimal[] Price = new decimal[] { 20.00m, 520.00m, 118.99m, 21.50m, 8.49m };
decimal[] Labor = new decimal[] { 5.00m, 40.00m, 25.99m, 9.99m, 7.00m };
```

I want to be able to take the PartName as input and pull and save the respective Price and Labor values to use for a total calculation later on.

I can't seem to figure out how to use my input to return column values based on its array position.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a class to represent a part?

Comment: Look into OOP. Even Functional languages would use something like structs over single arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly, you can find the index of an item using the [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0) method. You pass it an array and an item to search for, and it will return the index of the item (or `-1` if the item isn't found):

```
string partName = "BATTERY";
int partIndex = Array.IndexOf(PartName, partName);
decimal partPrice = Price[partIndex];
decimal partLabor = Labor[partIndex];
```

---

That being said, it's not very reliable to depend on separate arrays to hold data for items. A better method would be to use a simple class:

```
public class Part
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Labor { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a list of parts:

```
List<Part> partsList = new List<Part>
{
    new Part { Name = "WIPERBLADES", Price = 20.00m, Labor = 5.00m},
    new Part { Name = "TIRES", Price = 520.00m, Labor = 40.00m},
    new Part { Name = "BATTERY", Price = 118.99m, Labor = 25.99m},
    new Part { Name = "OIL", Price = 21.50m, Labor = 9.99m},
    new Part { Name = "OILFILTER", Price = 8.49m, Labor = 7.00m}
}
```

Now we can find a part by it's name, which returns a `Part` object that has the `Price` and `Labor` cost as properties of the object:

```
string partName = "BATTERY";
Part battery = partsList.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Name == partName);

// Now we have the Price and Labor values as: battery.Price and battery.Labor
```